# Unable to update the parent list after saving user inputs on a dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-navigation, android-mvvm

I'm building a sample application using MVVM and navigation components. Below is the navigation graph,

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_sample" app:startDestination="@id/FHomePage">
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/FHomePage"
        android:name="com.sample.FHomePage"
        android:label="layout_home_page" tools:layout="@layout/layout_layout_home_page">
    <action
            android:id="@+id/action_FHomePage_to_popup"
            app:destination="@id/popupDialog"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/FHomePage" />
</fragment>
<dialog
        android:id="@+id/popupDialog"
        android:name="com.sample.PopupDialog"
        android:label="layout_pop_up_dialog"
        tools:layout="@layout/layout_pop_up_dialog" />
```

This is a simple app that opens home page containing a list of items. On button click, it opens a dialog fragment- a small form which takes three text inputs from the user. When the user clicks save button, it should close the dialog, pass those values back to home page fragment and update the list

Here is the ViewModel for the home page

```
class HomePageViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val listItems = mutableListOf<FormEntity>() //used by recyclerview
    val listItemsLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<FormEntity>>()

    init {
       listItemsLiveData.postValue(listItems)
    }

    fun saveForm(value1: String, value2: String, value3: String) {
       listsItems.add(FormEntity(value1, value2, value3))
       listItemsLiveData.postValue(listItems)
    }
}
```

Meanwhile, the recyclerview listens to listItemsLiveData for any change on the home page

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list_items"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:data="@{viewModel.listItemsLiveData}"
            />
```

Recyclerview adapter uses data binding to update the list which is shown below

```
@BindingAdapter("data")
@JvmStatic fun setItems(recyclerView: RecyclerView, resource: List<FormEntity>?) {
    with(recyclerView.adapter as CustomListAdapter) {
        resource?.let { updateData(it) }
    }
}
```

The aforementioned binding will invoke the following in the adapter

```
fun updateData(items: List<FormEntity>) {
    this.items.clear()
    this.items.addAll(items)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

In Java, we can set the target fragments and invoke onActivityResult(...) method. However, I'm not sure how this can be done with navigation components in place. Shared ViewModels on Activity is suggested on some of the community posts. Not sure if that is the right way to do.

I tried a different approach though. From pop-up dialog fragment, when save button is clicked, I cal home page ViewModel to save the form

```
btn_save.setOnClickListener {
        viewModelObj.saveForm(
            value1,
            value2
            value3
        )
        dismiss()
}
```

viewModelObj is the home page ViewModel instance which is initiated again on the popup dialog

```
private val viewModelObj by lazy {
    ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(FHomePage::class.java)
}
```

On debug, when saving button on pop-up dialog is clicked, it passes the form data over to the ViewModel and it posts value to live data. However, the recyclerview adapter is not updating the list. Do you know what could potentially be blocking it?

Or do I need to add a new action on the navigation graph flowing from the dialog back to the home page with form data in the bundle?

Comment: So both of your Fragments are using the same `ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)` code?

Comment: The dialog fragment is a simple form whose input data will be used by the parent fragment, I thought to give it a try by using the same ViewModel. Do we need separate VM for that?

Comment: `DialogFragment` and `Fragements` should use shared viewmodel instance of your HomeViewModel, use debugger to *ensure* it is the same instance.